# Amazon CloudFront CDN download usage increasing (but not traffic nor requests)

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I’m looking for some advice or opinion as I’m not an expert in how Amazon CloudFront works.

I run an origin pull CDN through Amazon CloudFront for a self-hosted WordPress installation. It has been running since August 2012. Works perfectly.

Up until January my bill with Amazon CloudFront was quite constant. I do not host videos (always embedded YouTube but even that is rare). The only “big” files I host on my blog and which are shared through Amazon CloudFront service are occasional 1 or 2MB PDFs.

Since February of March, I’ve seen a significant increase in my Download Usage Report: it went from 10GB/month in January to 47GB/month for April.

However:

1) The number of HTTP request remains about the same: 150,000/month

2) My traffic is constant, did not significantly increased or decreased. It’s also modest: about 10,000 unique visits/month.

I’m wondering what could explain this increase.

Thanks,

P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to answer your question without additional information. For starter, I may suggest you to turn on logging for your CloudFront distribution in AWS [Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/home?#). Please note that although there is no extra charge for enabling access logging, you accrue the usual Amazon S3 charges for storing and accessing the files on Amazon S3 (you can delete them at any time).

CloudFront log file format is described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html).

If you really concerned with growing usage, the best way to get insight would be to open new case via [AWS Support Center](https://aws.amazon.com/support).

Comment: Thanks a lot: that will get me started it the right direction.